# Clear cache changes link language prefix in field

Tags: nodes, i18n-l10n, caching

We have a multilingual Drupal 7 install. On a lot of pages there are internal links to other pages in a textarea field, like the body field, example: 
When the node is saved, the internal link is changed to it's corresponding alias, example: http://www.domain.com/en/node-alias.

This works perfectly, until we clear the cache. If we clear the cache in the En version of the site, all the links will use the correct alias in this language version.
If we switch to another language, all the links in that language will use the language prefix of the language that was active when we cleared the cache.
So on the FR version a link would display as http://www.domain.com/en/node/999.

The node id is still correct, only the language prefix isn't the correct language. This means that the link goes to the 404 page.

Is there anyone who knows a solution for this?